# Angular: Lazy module loading does not work

Tags: angular, module

I try to achieve lazy module loading but I don't succeed yet.
I want when the user go to /admin - then the AdminModule will start,
and when the user go to /admin/user - then UserComponenet of AdminModule will start.

This is the folder structure of my app:
[image: app folder structure]

In my app I have **AppModule**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) }
 ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent html file:**

```
--- App Componenet --- <br /><br />
<a routerLink="admin">admin</a><br />
<a routerLink="admin/home">admin/home</a><br />
<a routerLink="admin/user">admin/user</a><br />

<br /><br />
Router outlet result: <br />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**AdminModule file:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

**HomeComponent html file:**

```
Home Works!
```

**UserComponent html file:**

```
User Works!
```

What am I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is this angular 8 or 9? by "then UserComponenet of AdminModule will start." you mean that the UserComponent will be downloaded to the browser?

Comment: angular 9. I mean I want to UserComponent to be loaded.

Comment: see **Manually Load Angular Component** in here: https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular/

Comment: Do you want to lazy load user component only when the admin/user is activated? Then you may want to look at [lazy load components](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8). What you are doing is just a lazy loading of modules which will load all the components within the module when any of the admin routes is activated.

Answer (score 2):

try to change AdminModule as follow

import CommonModule instead of BrowserModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-async-routing?file=src/app/admin/admin.module.ts)